# Jenkins dynamic paramters based on groovy method

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to do the below things as part of Jenkins pipeline dsl.

1. I have a yaml file where i store all my static values.
2. I created a pipeline job which should show 2 parameters.

a)region : northamerica/europe

b)environment : this should come based on the region selected.

3. I am defining the 2 functions outside of the pipeline so that i can use them during the parameters section.

Syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def yaml_file = "JenkinsFiles/environments.yaml"

def getRegions() {  
def var_regions = []

yaml_settings.environments.each  { key, value  -> var_regions.add(key) }
return var_regions
}

  def getEnvironments(String region) { 
  def var_envs = []

  yaml_settings.environments."${region}".non_prod.each { key, value  -> var_envs.add("\"" + key + "\"") }
  return var_envs    
}

environment {
yaml_settings = {}
}

pipeline {

agent 
{
 node 
{
  label 'docker'
} 
}

stages {
stage('Prepare') {
  steps{
        script{

          yaml_settings = readYaml file: "${yaml_file}"
          list_regions = getRegions()

           properties([
              parameters([
                  choice(choices: list_regions , description: 'Please select region to deploy', name: 'REGION'),
                  [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Please select environment to deploy', filterLength: 1, filterable: false, name: 'ACP_ENVIRONMENTS', randomName: 'choice-parameter-deploy-env', referencedParameters: 'REGION', script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ''], script: [classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: """
   envs = getEnvironments($REGION)
   return $envs
   """]]]])])}}}}}
```

Issue:
The getEnvironments method is not returning the value into the variable and its not getting effected in the parameter. But $region value is coming into though.I can do if else based on the reference parameter and get the value but i dont want to use if else coz i will get many values down the line.

HELP APPRECIATED!!

Answer (score 0):

As with many other questions, the issue here is that Jenkins needs to know the parameters *before* it executes your pipeline. Once the pipeline is running, the parameters have already been defined, and any change to the parameters won't impact *this* build.

You may want to take a look at the ActiveChoice plugin to address this.